# How to organize a project in Java?

Tags: java, class, project

My program is divided in 3 projects and the main goal was to parse a lot of datas (arround 20 000 files .csv).

- The first project is used to merge data.
- The second project is used to fill empty arrea in my new merged's datas.
- The third project is used to do some maths on this stock and save the results in new .csv.

The thing is, I don't know how to regroup my 3 projects in one (each one is about 1500 lines).
Should I do 3 classes as my program has 3 main goal?

Comment: Build each as Jar, link each Jar into a fourth project, call the APIs as needed

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MadProgrammer, I'm gonna try this and come back to say problem solve when it will be done.

Comment: *"Should I do 3 classes as my program has 3 main goal?"* You said each project has about 1500 lines. So do you think it would be useful to have a class with that many lines? So "no", you shouldn't create only 3 classes. (repost to fix typos)